# output group of json objects on new line instead of single line

Tags: python, arrays, json, object, newline

I am loading a json file and trying to pull some values then output that group of values by line.

The current output looks like this:

```
{"time":"1:2:2","post":"1","user":"4","text":"Masaru Emoto"}{"time":"1:3:8","post":"8","user":"5","text":"Meteors"}{"time":"7:4:5","post":"1","user":"8","text":"Olympics"}
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
{"time":"1:2:2","post":"1","user":"4","text":"Masaru Emoto"}
{"time":"1:3:8","post":"8","user":"5","text":"Meteors"}
{"time":"7:4:5","post":"1","user":"8","text":"Olympics"}
```

I can't figure out where to add the "\n" to fix the output. Thanks in advance for the help.

**Code:**

```
import json

json_data = open('somefile.json', 'r+').read().decode("utf-8")
jdata = json.loads(json_data)

def id_generator(d):    

with open('formatted_file' + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            id_generator(v)                    
        if isinstance(v, list):            
            for post in v:
                formated = {"time":post.get('created_time'),"user":post['from']['id'],
                               "post":post.get('id'),"text":post.get('description')}                                        
                out = json.dumps(formated, separators=(',', ':'))                                                         
                outfile.write(out)                                        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        id_generator(jdata)
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Comment: `outfile.write(out + '\n')` ?

Comment: I cannot see any difference in the _current output_ and the _look like this_ output.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979 I think someone edited it, it originally wouldn't add the newline character, so the output was a single string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formating kinda broke your message, but I assume you want to newline after each write call (each post).

Just do `outfile.write(out + '\n')`. The `\n` will be automagically converted to proper line separator on given system.

Comment: nailed it! I fight with the formatting EVERY TIME I ask a question. Thanks for the help.