# Output group of json objects on new lines instead of single line

Tags: json, python-3.x, pretty-print

Currently, my json data is formatted as:

```
{"1": {"name": "camera", "aisle": "M.53", "status": "Out of Stock"}, "2": {"name": "camera", "aisle": "M.36", "status": "In Stock"}, "3": {"name": "camera", "aisle": "M.38", "status": "In Stock"}}
```

I would like to reformat the 'block' of data so that it prints each 'group' of data is on its on line. The data does not need to remain in json format - I simply want to break up the information into individual lines (similar to the following):

```
 "1": {"name": "camera", "aisle": "M.53", "status": "Out of Stock"}, 
 "2": {"name": "camera", "aisle": "M.36", "status": "In Stock"}, 
 "3": {"name": "camera", "aisle": "M.38", "status": "In Stock"}
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
 result = json.loads(data['searchResults'])['results'][0]
        summary = {
            'name': result['name'],
            'aisle': result['price']['aisle'][0],
            'status': result['inventory']['status'],
            }
        results[store] = summary

with open('Testing.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('\n')
    json.dump(results, outfile)
```

What is a recommended way to go about adding the line breaks?

Comment: If the format is that crucial, you may have to implement it yourself or look for a third party module with more configuration - as far as I'm aware, the standard library `json` module only provides the two options you've already seen.

Comment: I've also tried what's posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589040/output-group-of-json-objects-on-new-line-instead-of-single-line but haven't had much luck with my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse json data in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537153/parse-json-data-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Python [PrettyPrint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-python-prettyprint-a-json-file).
Hope this helps :)

Edit:
Apologies, I should have been clearer.
I used the following test code and achieved your desired output:

```
import json

#example json from your question as text
before_parsed = '{"1": {"name": "camera", "aisle": "M.53", "status": "Out of Stock"}, "2": {"name": "camera", "aisle": "M.36", "status": "In Stock"}, "3": {"name": "camera", "aisle": "M.38", "status": "In Stock"}}'

#parsing the text to get the results as a json object
results = json.loads(before_parsed)

#print (results)

#############copy the code from here to your program################
#sorting your json output by keys so that you get your output as {"1":{}, "2":{}...}
results_str = json.dumps(results, sort_keys=True)

#removing the outer brackets {}, now the results_str would look something like this "1":{}, "2":{}...
results_str = results_str[1:-1]

#splitting the string by "}," as delimiter, so results_list would look like this ["1":{, "2":{, "3":{}]
results_list = results_str.split("},")

#print the results to the file as per the desired format
with open('Testing.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('\n')
    for p in results_list[:-1]:
        print (p+'}', file=outfile)
    print (results_list[-1], file=outfile)
```

And the following is printed to Testing.txt file:

```
"1": {"aisle": "M.53", "name": "camera", "status": "Out of Stock"}
"2": {"aisle": "M.36", "name": "camera", "status": "In Stock"}
"3": {"aisle": "M.38", "name": "camera", "status": "In Stock"}
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you or if this is not what you are looking for. 
Cheers!

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Link-only answers are difficult to understand and are susceptible to become invalid if the website is down or not working. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can reproduce the most relevant portions of the link/blog you are referring to into this post itself.

Comment: I've looked at the referenced answer but am still unsure how to apply. Can you provide any more guidance to get me in the right direction?